# How to make a screen resolution aware program in WinForms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, screen

Hi everyone i have a problem, i designed a program in a enviroment where the screen resolution is  1600x900, the problem is that when i tried to execute the program in other resolutions for example 1366x768 all my buttons, panels etc, are cropped by the window, here a example  at 1600x900 [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDzqa.png)   and here at 1366x768  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLMvD.png) i used anchor and fill properties but it doesn't  work, do you know any property or solution for solve this, i will be very grateful

Comment: You can fix this by reading anchor and dock properties when dealing with winforms. See this link [Anchor Property MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @P.Pat So basically what he said he's tried?

Comment: @john OP said he tried anchor and fill. I suggested reading anchor and dock properties which would guide OP in fixing the issue.

Comment: @P.Pat What is fill? :) It's a Dock type...

Comment: @john then give OP a better suggestion instead of questioning a comment that may possibly help him. The term "reading" will help him fix the issue wont it?

Comment: I'm not sure your link will help in this case since it appears each box should scale with the UI. It would be difficult to combine anchor and dock to achieve that, if possible. So not only has he tried that, but it seems unlikely that reading about what he's already tried will help, hence my comment. He should try using the TableLayoutPanel instead.

Comment: Try `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel`

Comment: @Lava1994 Perhaps you should explain what you would consider "correct" behavior for your application: crop, scroll, shrink to invisibility, reboot? How should fonts behave? We can't intuit from "doesn't work" what _working_ would look like. Since you've tagged the question with `asp.net`, should we assume you want to support the full range of devices from watches to jumbotrons?

Comment: It certainly appears that a `TableLayoutPanel` with two rows with a height of 50% each and four columns with a width of 25% each is what you want. You can then put one control (or group of controls on a single parent, e.g. `Panel`) into each cell and then use `Dock` and/or `Anchor` within each cell.  See here for an example: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630636-Anchor-amp-Dock-For-Automatic-Resizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

core property  also try to use split container it will automatically resize your form as per resolution

try to use this code on form load

```
public void abrunden(object was, int x, int y, int width, int height, int radius)
{

    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();

    gp.AddLine(x + radius, y, x + width - radius, y);
    gp.AddArc(x + width - radius, y, radius, radius, 270, 90);
    gp.AddLine(x + width, y + radius, x + width, y + height - radius);
    gp.AddArc(x + width - radius, y + height - radius, radius, radius, 0, 90);
    gp.AddLine(x + width - radius, y + height, x + radius, y + height);
    gp.AddArc(x, y + height - radius, radius, radius, 90, 90);
    gp.AddLine(x, y + height - radius, x, y + radius);
    gp.AddArc(x, y, radius, radius, 180, 90);
    gp.CloseFigure();

    was.region = new System.Drawing.Region(gp);
    gp.Dispose();
}
```

to call this Use following

1. use one panel in form dock this with form
2. pass panel name width and height to method

> abrunden(panWarten, 0, 0, _with1.Width, _with1.Height, 20);

this will make form responsive as per screen